# entity must be null for http method GET

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to consume an external api exposed a payment provider.
I user Jersey and javax.ws.rs for request, because I can easily send authent with Digest.

But when it comes to make the request, a GET with payload, Jersey returns

```
> IllegalStateException. Entity must be null for http method GET
```

```
CashTransactionResponse responseData = null;
//We connect to intouch server
String requestUrl = rootUrlTouchPay + agency.getAgencyCode() + "/" + IntouchMethodApis.TRANSACTION + "?loginAgent=" + agency.getLogin() + "&passwordAgent=" + agency.getPassword();

ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
//Open Digest authentication
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.digest(BASIC_LOGIN, BASIC_PWD);
clientConfig.register(feature);

clientConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class);
//Create new rest client
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION, true);
//Set the url
WebTarget webTarget = client.target(requestUrl);
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

logger.info("Initialisation of cashout service successful for cash");

// create request
Gson gson = new Gson();
String transactionString = gson.toJson(cashRequest);

Response response = null;
// start the response
if (cashRequest.getServiceCode().contains(TelecomEnum.WAVE.name().toUpperCase())) {
    response = invocationBuilder.method("GET", Entity.entity(transactionString, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
} else {
    response = invocationBuilder.put(Entity.entity(transactionString, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
}
```

Please how could i do to send my GET request with body ?

Thanks

Comment: GET doesn't have a payload, by RFC 2616. Try POST.

Comment: @user207421 i don't have access to the remote server, hosted by a bank provider. They created it like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in

> Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
> clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION, true);

The `client` copied the values from `clientConfig` and any further settings on `clientConfig` do not have any impact on the `client`.

Either switch the lines or set the `ClientProperties.SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION` property on the `client`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing an `invocationBuilder.method("GET", ...)`, use `invocationBuilder.post(entity)`, as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#post-javax.ws.rs.client.Entity-). This will allow you to POST your transaction String to the endpoint.

Comment: the remote server is waiting for GET that's why i send a GET.

Comment: that's fine, but then send the GET without a body.

Comment: the body must contain some data they use to process my request on server side.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding on your end. You either send the GET without the body, or a POST with body. So, why in theory you could send a body with a GET request, [it's never useful to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body).